# How to determine if a JavaScript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
vendors = [{
    Name: 'Magenic',
    ID: 'ABC'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Microsoft',
    ID: 'DEF'
  } // and so on...
];
```

How do I check this array to see if "Magenic" exists? I don't want to loop, unless I have to. I'm working with potentially a couple of thousand records.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

**2018 edit**: This answer is from 2011, before browsers had widely supported array filtering methods and arrow functions. Have a look at [CAFxX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217584/104999).

There is no "magic" way to check for something in an array without a loop. Even if you use some function, the function itself will use a loop. What you can do is break out of the loop as soon as you find what you're looking for to minimize computational time.

```
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i < vendors.length; i++) {
    if (vendors[i].Name == 'Magenic') {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that [Keith's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-json-array-contains-object/8217459#8217459) is also very viable and saves you from looping.

Comment: You don't need a flag if all you need to know is whether or not "something" is in, you can just check the value of the scan index with the size of array. For this to work the index var needs to be declared before the for statement of course.

Comment: These options seem to work now: vendors.forEach, vendors.filter, vendors.reduce

Comment: what about JSON.stringify(vendors).indexOf('Magenic') !== -1

Comment: @LastBreath that could result in a false positive quite easily if `'Magenic'` is somewhere else in the object

Comment: WARNING: The wrong answer has been marked as correct.

Comment: @arled This is the answer that originally solved this for OP, and it's valid to let it keep the credit for that. Especially since it mentions in bold that it's outdated, linking to the modern answer.

Comment: @EgorHans It's also OK to move the check mark when things change. Luckily SO fixed this issue by unpinning the accepted answer so it's less likely to confuse people who didn't scroll down in the past.

Comment: "2018 edit..." -- you can simply update the answer when things change. "There is no "magic" way to check for something in an array without a loop" -- `some` is magic!

Answer (score 2159):

There isn't any need to reinvent the <del>wheel</del> loop, at least not explicitly.

Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as it allows the browser to stop as soon as one element is found that matches:

```
if (vendors.some(e => e.Name === 'Magenic')) {
  // We found at least one object that we're looking for!
}
```

or the equivalent (in this case) with [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which returns the found object instead of a boolean:

```
if (vendors.find(e => e.Name === 'Magenic')) {
  // Usually the same result as above, but find returns the element itself
}
```

If you'd like to get the position of that element, use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
const i = vendors.findIndex(e => e.Name === 'Magenic');
if (i > -1) {
  // We know that at least 1 object that matches has been found at the index i
}
```

If you need to get *all* of the objects that match:

```
if (vendors.filter(e => e.Name === 'Magenic').length > 0) {
  // The same result as above, but filter returns all objects that match
}
```

If you need compatibility with really old browsers that don't support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), then your best bet is:

```
if (vendors.filter(function(e) { return e.Name === 'Magenic'; }).length > 0) {
  // The same result as above, but filter returns all objects that match and we avoid an arrow function for compatibility
}
```

Comment: @CAFxX How would you get the index when found? is this even a possibility or would a loop work better to get the index?

Comment: @Echtniet if you need the index then vendors.findIndex will give you the  index of the first matching element. If instead you need the value then either vendors.find will give the first matching element, or vendors.filter will give you all matching elements. You may want to refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Why is `some` *better yet* ?

Comment: @7hibault because `some` can short circuit once an object with `name === "Magenic"` is found. With `filter`, it will check each item till the end of the array and create a new array items which match the condition, then check the `length`

Comment: Lots of comments about `.some`. It's 2019, use `.some` and use Polyfills to support lousy browsers and move on with you life... polyfill.io/v3/url-builder. The only thing I can see is that if you can't support arrow functions then it's as simple as the Polyfill I mentioned and: `arr.some(function(i) { return i.Name === "Magenic" })`

Comment: Side note: I [checked on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_some), and `.some` itself is widespread. Even IE supports it, except for archaic versions.

Comment: To add to @CAFxX .some solution, you can use an external variable with Array.some like this:

`const externalVariable = 'My custom Name';
if (vendors.some(function(element) { e.Name === this}, externalVariable)) {
  /* vendors contains the element we're looking for */
}`

Comment: How do I get the index after if that element does exist?

Comment: @CyberAvater https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e/8217584?noredirect=1#comment86332057_8217584

Comment: many many thanks  this method saved me. I was trying about 48 hour to solve my problem. finally it's solved by this 

if (vendors.filter(e => e.Name === 'Magenic').length > 0) {
  /* vendors contains the element we're looking for */
}

Comment: Shall start a petition to accept this as selected answer.

Answer (score 217):

No loop necessary. Three methods that come to mind:

**Array.prototype.some()**

This is the most exact answer for your question, i.e. "check if something exists", implying a bool result. This will be true if there are any 'Magenic' objects, false otherwise:

```
let hasMagenicVendor = vendors.some( vendor => vendor['Name'] === 'Magenic' )
```

**Array.prototype.filter()**

This will return an array of all 'Magenic' objects, even if there is only one (will return a one-element array):

```
let magenicVendors = vendors.filter( vendor => vendor['Name'] === 'Magenic' )
```

If you try to coerce this to a boolean, it will not work, as an empty array (no 'Magenic' objects) is still truthy. So just use `magenicVendors.length` in your conditional.

**Array.prototype.find()**

This will return the first 'Magenic' object (or `undefined` if there aren't any):

```
let magenicVendor = vendors.find( vendor => vendor['Name'] === 'Magenic' );
```

This coerces to a boolean okay (any object is truthy, `undefined` is falsy).

---

Note: I'm using vendor["Name"] instead of vendor.Name because of the weird casing of the property names.

Note 2: No reason to use loose equality (==) instead of strict equality (===) when checking the name.

Comment: It's useful to point out that under the hood, these are all looping. These are also all slower computationally than simply for looping and performing operations.

Comment: May as well go share that love here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748670/why-are-native-array-functions-are-so-much-slower-then-loop so more people like me don't navigate to that old page and make assumptions.

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle: True!! Though developer hours are often more expensive compared to users' CPU hours (and less code is often nice).

Answer (score 82):

The accepted answer still works but now we have an ECMAScript 6 native methods `[Array.find][1]` and `[Array.some][2]` to achieve the same effect.

**Array.some**

Use `some` If you only want to determine if an element exists i.e. you need a `true/false` determination.

Quoting MDN:

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

**Array.find**

Use find if you want to get the matched object from array else returns `undefined`.

Quoting MDN:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    id: 21,
    label: 'Banana',
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    label: 'Apple',
  }
]

/* note : data is the actual object that matched search criteria 
  or undefined if nothing matched */

let data = arr.find(function(ele) {
    return ele.id === 21;
});

if (data) {
    console.log('found');
    console.log(data); // This is entire object i.e. `item` not boolean
}


/* note : doesExist is a boolean thats true or false depending on of whether the data was found or not */
let doesExist = arr.some(function(ele) {
    return ele.id === 21;
});
```

See my [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xp3tdovs) There is a polyfill for IE [provided by mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Could be shorter if you just do `return ele.id == '2'`, but +1 for a good ES6 solution.

Comment: Good to have fresh answer :) Just wondering if performance are better or not than answers above...

Comment: I think it is important to point out that the return value of 'data' (when ele.id matches an id, such as '21') is going to be the array item itself (in this case, the whole item object).

If the expectation was that the data variable result would be 'true' or 'false' instead of a falsy value, you would be sorely disappointed.

Comment: Thx! My task was a bit different. Get the index of Object in the Array => `push if <0 || splice(index, 1)`
here is my a bit updated code:
`const index = this.selected.indexOf(this.selected.find(s => s.id == passedObj.id))`

Comment: This code only works if `return ele.id === 21;`; it's a number, not a string.

Answer (score 52):

Here's the way I'd do it

```
const found = vendors.some(item => item.Name === 'Magenic');
```

`array.some()` method checks if there is at least one value in an array that matches criteria and returns a boolean. 
From here on you can go with:

```
if (found) {
// do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Unless you want to restructure it like this:

```
vendors = {
    Magenic: {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     },
    Microsoft: {
      Name: 'Microsoft',
      ID: 'DEF'
    } and so on... 
};
```

to which you can do `if(vendors.Magnetic)`

You will have to loop

Comment: In case he still wanted to maintain the object structure to use it else where

Comment: how would you do that?

Answer (score 28):

A JavaScript array has two methods, the `some` and `every` methods that return a Boolean and can help you achieve this.

I think `some` would be most appropriate for what you intend to achieve.

```
vendors.some(vendor => vendor['Name'] !== 'Magenic')
```

Some validates that any of the objects in the array satisfies the given condition.

```
vendors.every(vendor => vendor['Name'] !== 'Magenic')
```

*every* validates that all the objects in the array satisfies the given condition.

Comment: @ThanwaCh. - it should return false! In your case you need to use ```array.some``` method!

Answer (score 26):

As per the [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) specification, you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

`const magenicIndex = vendors.findIndex(vendor => vendor.Name === 'Magenic');`

`magenicIndex` will hold either `0` (which is the index in the array) or `-1` if it wasn't found.

Comment: Just to make people aware that 0 would still match as a false result if that was used as the condition. For this reason I think find() is better as you get a more _logical_ truthy evaluation.

Comment: Not only what @dhj mentioned, but also, it might be found at a later index (1, 2 etc). As such, you'll need to check whether the index is at least 0, so most solutions that directly yield a boolean-usable value will be more elegant.

Answer (score 23):

As the OP has asked the question **if the key exists or not**:

A more elegant solution that will return a Boolean using the [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) *[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)* function can be:

```
const magenicVendorExists = vendors.reduce((accumulator, vendor) => (accumulator||vendor.Name === "Magenic"), false);
```

**Note:**  The initial parameter of reduce is a `false` and if the array has the key it will return true.

Comment: Please also check Mirza Leka's solution. A much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot without looking into the object really.

You probably should change your structure a little, like

```
vendors = {
    Magenic:   'ABC',
    Microsoft: 'DEF'
};
```

Then you can just use it like a lookup-hash.

```
vendors['Microsoft']; // 'DEF'
vendors['Apple']; // undefined
```

Answer (score 12):

```
const check = vendors.find((item)=>item.Name==='Magenic')

console.log(check)
```

Try this code.

If the item or element is present then the output will show you that element. If it is not present then the output will be 'undefined'.

Answer (score 11):

### Testing for array elements:

JavaScript offers array functions which allow you to achieve this relatively easily. They are the following:

1. `Array.prototype.filter`: Takes a callback function which is a test, the array is then iterated over with is callback and filtered according to this callback. **A new filtered array is returned.**
2. `Array.prototype.some`:  Takes a callback function which is a test, the array is then iterated over with is callback and **if any element passes the test,** **the boolean true is returned. Otherwise false is returned**

The specifics are best explained via an example:

### Example:

```js
vendors = [
    {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     },
    {
      Name: 'Microsoft',
      ID: 'DEF'
    } //and so on goes array...
];

// filter returns a new array, we instantly check if the length
// is longer than zero of this newly created array
if (vendors.filter(company => company.Name === 'Magenic').length ) {
  console.log('I contain Magenic');
}

// some would be a better option then filter since it directly returns a boolean
if (vendors.some(company => company.Name === 'Magenic')) {
  console.log('I also contain Magenic');
}
```

### Browser support:

These 2 function are `ES6` function, not all browsers might support them. To overcome this you can use a polyfill. Here is the polyfill for `Array.prototype.some` (from MDN):

```js
if (!Array.prototype.some) {
  Array.prototype.some = function(fun, thisArg) {
    'use strict';

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined');
    }

    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t && fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Simplest method so far:

```js
if (vendors.findIndex(item => item.Name == "Magenic") == -1) {
  //not found item
} else {
  //found item 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

My approach to solving this problem is to use ES6 and creating a function that does the check for us. The benefit of this function is that it can be reusable through out your project to check any array of objects given the `key` and the `value` to check.

**ENOUGH TALK, LET'S SEE THE CODE**

**Array**

```js
const ceos = [
  {
    name: "Jeff Bezos",
    company: "Amazon"
  }, 
  {
    name: "Mark Zuckerberg",
    company: "Facebook"
  }, 
  {
    name: "Tim Cook",
    company: "Apple"
  }
];
```

**Function**

```js
const arrayIncludesInObj = (arr, key, valueToCheck) => {
  return arr.some(value => value[key] === valueToCheck);
}
```

**Call/Usage**

```js
const found = arrayIncludesInObj(ceos, "name", "Tim Cook"); // true

const found = arrayIncludesInObj(ceos, "name", "Tim Bezos"); // false
```

Comment: @SebastianSimon i have updated my code. I want less experienced when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 7):

#### 2021 Solution*

Lodash `.some` ([documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#some)) is a clean solution, if you use the `_matchesProperty` ([documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#matchesProperty)) shorthand:

```js
_.some(VENDORS, ['Name', 'Magenic'])
```

#### Explanation

This will iterate through the `VENDORS` Array, looking for an element Object with the `Name` key having a value of the String `'Magenic'`. Once it finds this element, it returns `true` and stops iterating. If it doesn't find the element after looking through the entire Array, it returns `false`.

#### Code snippet

```js
const VENDORS = [{ Name: 'Magenic', ID: 'ABC' }, { Name: 'Microsoft', ID: 'DEF' }];

console.log(_.some(VENDORS, ['Name', 'Magenic'])); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

`*` Note that this uses the popular Lodash library to achieve the simplest/shortest possible solution. I'm offering this as an alternative to the existing [vanilla JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) solutions, for those who are interested.

Answer (score 6):

You have to loop. There isn't any way around it.

```
function seekVendor(vendors, name) {
  for (var i=0, l=vendors.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (typeof vendors[i] == "object" && vendors[i].Name === name) {
      return vendors[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you could use a library like [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) to make this more pleasing:

```
Enumerable.From(vendors).Where("$.Name == 'Magenic'").First();
```

(see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/NxChZ/) for a demo)

I doubt that linq.js will be faster than a straightforward loop, but it certainly is more flexible when things get a little more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Correct me if I'm wrong...

I could have used the `forEach` method like this,

```
var found = false;
vendors.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.name === "name"){
        found = true;
    }
});
```

Nowadays I'm used to it, because of its simplicity and self-explanatory word.

Comment: Note: no use of return here

Answer (score 6):

Functions `map`, `filter`, `find`, and similar are slower than the simple loop.
For me they also less readable than the simple loop and harder to debug. Using them looks like a kind of irrational ritual.

Better have something like this:

```
 arrayHelper = {
     arrayContainsObject: function (array, object, key){
         for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if (object[key] === array[i][key]){
                 return true;
            }
         }
         return false;
     }
     
   };
```

And use it like this with given OP example:

```
    vendors = [{
    Name: 'Magenic',
    ID: 'ABC'
     },
     {
    Name: 'Microsoft',
    ID: 'DEF'
     } 
  ];

let abcObject = {ID: 'ABC', Name: 'Magenic'};

let isContainObject = arrayHelper.arrayContainsObject(vendors, abcObject, 'ID');
```

Comment: map, filter, find are more readable and code is also smaller and quicker to write

Comment: Why are they much slower than the simple loop? As far as I know, they'll have the same time complexity as their simple loop equivalents. For example, both of your codes look like O(n) to me.

Comment: above method `arrayContainsObject` is supposed to be a library method that you write once and forget.  You actually can write it using array functions if you prefer. And nothing can beat `arrayHelper.arrayContainsObject` from the point of readability.

Comment: @Michael Fulton
https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/ This article with a benchmark states for loops 3 times faster.

Comment: Why not make it return the index at which the property is found, this will cover both the question and the findinex mentioned in other answers and requested in other comments?

Comment: @JulioSpinelli. Agree, why not? But then we should rename our method to be like `findIndexOfObject`. So, better to have them both.

Comment: bad practice instead use my answer

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) you can take advantage of grep to create array with all matching objects:

```
var results = $.grep(vendors, function (e) {
    return e.Name == "Magenic";
});
```

and then use the results array:

```
for (var i=0, l=results.length; i<l; i++) {
    console.log(results[i].ID);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash). If the Lodash library is too heavy for your application, consider chunking out unnecessary functions not used.

```
let newArray = filter(_this.props.ArrayOne, function(item) {
                    return find(_this.props.ArrayTwo, {"speciesId": item.speciesId});
                });
```

This is just one way to do this. Another one can be:

```
var newArray=  [];
     _.filter(ArrayOne, function(item) {
                        return AllSpecies.forEach(function(cItem){
                            if (cItem.speciesId == item.speciesId){
                              newArray.push(item);
                          }
                        })
                    });
```

`console.log(arr);`

The above example can also be **rewritten without using any** libraries like:

```
var newArray=  [];
ArrayOne.filter(function(item) {
                return ArrayTwo.forEach(function(cItem){
                    if (cItem.speciesId == item.speciesId){
                      newArray.push(item);
                  }
                })
            });
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Many answers here are good and pretty easy. But if your array of objects is having a fixed set of values then you can use the below trick:

Map all the names in a object.

```
vendors = [
    {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     },
    {
      Name: 'Microsoft',
      ID: 'DEF'
    }
];

var dirtyObj = {}
for(var count=0;count<vendors.length;count++){
   dirtyObj[vendors[count].Name] = true //or assign which gives you true.
}
```

Now this dirtyObj you can use again and again without any loop.

```
if(dirtyObj[vendor.Name]){
  console.log("Hey! I am available.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To compare one object to another, I combine a for in loop (used to loop through objects) and some().
You do not have to worry about an array going out of bounds etc, so that saves some code. Documentation on .some can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var productList = [{id: 'text3'}, {id: 'text2'}, {id: 'text4', product: 'Shampoo'}]; // Example of selected products
var theDatabaseList = [{id: 'text1'}, {id: 'text2'},{id: 'text3'},{id:'text4', product: 'shampoo'}];    
var  objectsFound = [];

for(let objectNumber in productList){
    var currentId = productList[objectNumber].id;   
    if (theDatabaseList.some(obj => obj.id === currentId)) {
        // Do what you need to do with the matching value here
        objectsFound.push(currentId);
    }
}
console.log(objectsFound);
```

An alternative way I compare one object to another is to use a nested for loop with Object.keys().length to get the amount of objects in the array. Code below:

```
var productList = [{id: 'text3'}, {id: 'text2'}, {id: 'text4', product: 'Shampoo'}]; // Example of selected products
var theDatabaseList = [{id: 'text1'}, {id: 'text2'},{id: 'text3'},{id:'text4', product: 'shampoo'}];    
var objectsFound = [];

for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(productList).length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < Object.keys(theDatabaseList).length; j++){
        if(productList[i].id === theDatabaseList[j].id){
            objectsFound.push(productList[i].id);
        }       
    }
}
console.log(objectsFound);
```

To answer your exact question, if are just searching for a value in an object, you can use a single for in loop.

```
var vendors = [
    {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     },
    {
      Name: 'Microsoft',
      ID: 'DEF'
    } 
];

for(var ojectNumbers in vendors){
    if(vendors[ojectNumbers].Name === 'Magenic'){
        console.log('object contains Magenic');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do:

```
const find = (key, needle) => return !!~vendors.findIndex(v => (v[key] === needle));
```

Comment: you'd better say why he can do that

Answer (score 2):

`var without2 = (arr, args) => arr.filter(v => v.id !== args.id);`

Example:

`without2([{id:1},{id:1},{id:2}],{id:2})`

Result:
without2([{id:1},{id:1},{id:2}],{id:2})

Comment: I think you meant to say Result: [{id:1},{id:1}]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. It works for me.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

var arr = [
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Gabriel',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    id: 3
  }
]

function findValue(arr,value) {
  return _.filter(arr, function (object) {
    return object['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  });
}

console.log(findValue(arr,'jack'))
//[ { name: 'Jack', id: 1 } ]
```

Comment: Well this is a really old question and I think its update already has the best solution nowadays.

Comment: Not everyone uses lodash or wants this dependency. How does the language do it best?

Answer (score 2):

```
const a = [{one:2},{two:2},{two:4}]
const b = a.filter(val => "two" in val).length;
if (b) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please and some description and make sure the example you provide works.. (filter will not change the original array but clone it).

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question. When you wrote this answer, the title was “How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?”. You’re checking if an object has a property on its prototype chain, not if the property of an object has a specific value.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon ” The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.” from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: @user1665355 Yes, correct. That’s what I said.

Answer (score 1):

**array of objects**

```
const array = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Doe' }
];
```

**Function to check if array contains an object with attribute value**

```
function containsObjectWithAttribute(array, attribute, value) {
    return array.some(obj => obj[attribute] === value);
}
```

**Example usage**

```
const attributeName = 'id'; // attribute to check
const targetValue = 2; // value to search for
const result = containsObjectWithAttribute(array, attributeName, targetValue);

console.log(result); // Output: true (because the array contains an object with id equal to 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const arrOfObj = [
    { id: 1, name: "askavy" },
    { id: 2, name: "james" },
    { id: 3, name: "mark" },
  ] ;

  const valueCheck = "mark"

  const index = arrOfObj.findIndex((obj) => {
     return obj.name === valueCheck ;
  }) ;

  (index === -1) ? console.log("Value does not exist") : console.log("Value Exist" ) ;

//--------------------------- 

  const exist = arrOfObj.some((obj) => {
     return obj.name === valueCheck ;
  }) ;

  (exist) ? console.log("Value Exist") : console.log("Value does not Exist") ;
```

Answer (score -5):

I would rather go with regex.

If your code is as follows,

```
vendors = [
    {
      Name: 'Magenic',
      ID: 'ABC'
     },
    {
      Name: 'Microsoft',
      ID: 'DEF'
    }
];
```

I would recommend

```
/"Name":"Magenic"/.test(JSON.stringify(vendors))
```

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: File this under, just because you can do something, does not mean that you should.

Comment: Snark and humor aside. There are several easy object and array access and iteration methods and expressions. Why would regex ever be your choice here? The question was how to determine if an array contains an object with a property whose value matches `"Magenic"`. False positives for your regex answer: `[ { "Not the property you’re looking for": { "Name": "Magenic" } } ]`, or `[ { 'Not the property you’re looking for"Name': "Magenic" } ]`; potential false negative (not if question asks for _own_ property, specifically): `[ Object.create({ Name: "Magenic" }) ]`.