# Javascript filter is slow

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two large arrays in my node application.

```
var styles = [{itemID:..., styleID:..., styleNum:..., otherFields...}]; // 42455 items
var products = [{productID:..., styleNum:..., otherFields...}]; // 72K items
```

I need to loop through the products and get the associated styleID from the styles array and add a new item into a new array. The styles array is sorted by styleNum. Here is what I have tried:

```
var i=0, len = products.length, items = new Array(products.length);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    var workingItem = products[i];
    var styleID = filterStyles(workingItem.styleNum)[0].styleID; 
    var item = {styleID:..., other fields};
    items[i]=item; 
}
```

...

```
function filterStyles(styleNum) 
{
    var results = [];
    var item;
    for (var i = 0, len = createdStyles.length; i < len; i++) 
    {
        item = createdStyles[i];
        if (item.styleNum == styleNum) results.push(item);
    }
    return results;
}
```

This is very slow, it takes 1 second to iterate over 100 items from my products array. I tried the same using asyc.each, but get the same response time. 
When I remove the filter function, it's lighting fast. Is there any way for me to improve my filter function?

Comment: Why not use the native `Array.prototype.filter` function?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan How would that help performance?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Native filter function is slower.

Comment: It would use native code for the iteration rather than an interpreted for loop.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Does not make it faster, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748670/why-are-native-array-functions-are-so-much-slower-then-loop

Comment: Two-year old questions pointing to proof from a website that's offline... Not the greatest relevance, but I'll concede the point. I asked the question since it seemed obvious to use the thing called "filter" when you want to filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid scanning the array every time `O(n2)`, you could create a map keyed by `styleNum`.

```
var styleNumMap = Object.create(null);
styles.forEach(function(style) {
    if (!styleNumMap[style.styleNum]) {
        styleNumMap[style.styleNum] = [];
    }
    styleNumMap[style.styleNum].push(style);
});
```

Then you can just do

```
var i=0, len = products.length, items = new Array(products.length);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    var workingItem = products[i];
    var styleID = styleNumMap[workingItem.styleNum][0].styleID; 
    var item = {styleID:..., other fields};
    items[i]=item; 
}
```

Comment: Little type though. styleNumMap[styleNum].push(style); should be styleNumMap[style.styleNum].push(style);

Comment: Lovely, transferring from array to keyed object improved my loading time by 12 seconds on an array of 1600 elements.