# How to check object has existed or not in Array - Basic Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a basic problem with Javascript. This code is below.

```js
var users = [{"user":{"id":1,"username":"google"}},{"user":{"id":2,"username":"yahoo"}}]

const result = users.filter(users.id === 1);

console.log(result);
```

I want to get result if `user_id` exist in array or not.

The error is:

```
false is not a function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `reduce` instead:

```js
var users = [{"user":{"id":1,"username":"google"}},{"user":{"id":2,"username":"yahoo"}}]

const result = users.reduce((s, user) => s || user.user.id === 1, false);

console.log(result);
```

`.filter` returns an array, while `.reduce` can return whatever you want (in this case, a boolean).

If you want to use `.filter`, try:

```js
var users = [{"user":{"id":1,"username":"google"}},{"user":{"id":2,"username":"yahoo"}}]

const result = !!users.filter(user => user.user.id === 1).length;

console.log(result);
```

However, keep in mind that `.filter` will create an extra array and might not be as efficient as `.reduce`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: i will vote the best for your answer. Can you add solution with .filter return Boolean

Comment: @FeedGit Sure. Added.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a callback to the function. This will return you the items which `id` is 1.

```js
const users = [{"user":{"id":1,"username":"google"}},{"user":{"id":2,"username":"yahoo"}}]

const result = users.filter(user => user.user.id === 1);

console.log(result);
```

Also instead of `checking` the length, you can use `some` function. This will terminate check of the rest items if any item was found.

```js
const users = [{"user":{"id":1,"username":"google"}},{"user":{"id":2,"username":"yahoo"}}]

const result = users.some(user => user.user.id === 1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: This solution is best for me.!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a callback, like an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), with the right properties to the `id`, because you have a nested structure for every user.

```js
var users = [{ user: { id: 1, username: "google" } }, { user: { id:2, username: "yahoo" } }];

const result = users.filter(user => user.user.id === 1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are writing the function in a wrong way

Try like this

```
const result = users.filter(x => x.user.id === 1);
console.log(result);
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/jcLuykdx/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```js
var users = [{"user":{"id":1,"username":"google"}},{"user":{"id":2,"username":"yahoo"}}]

const result = users[0].user.id;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = [{"user":{"id":1,"username":"google"}},{"user":
{"id":2,"username":"yahoo"}}]

const result = users.filter(function(el){
return (el.user.id===1)
});

console.log(result[0].user.username);
//This will print the username of the object with id==1 in array
```