# Why includes() is not working good in my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I  have a problem with this function in React:

```
createContact = (item) => {
        let items = this.state.items;
        let email = this.state.email;

        if (items.length < 10 && 
            items.includes(email) === false &&
            EmailValidator.validate(email) === true) {
            this.setState(state => ({
                button: true,
                items: state.items.concat([ item ]),
                info: '✔ You have successfully added an user.'
            }))
        }
        else if (EmailValidator.validate(email) === false) {
            this.setState(state => ({
                button: true,
                items: state.items,
                info: '! User has\'t been added - the email was invalid. Try again!'
            }))
        }
        else if (items.includes(email) === true){
            this.setState(state => ({
                button: false,
                items: state.items,
                info: '! This email exists on this list.'
            }))
        }
    }
```

The problem is, with this part of code `items.includes(email)`.
I used this part of code to check, if email is on list if not.
But this always return 'false' - if email exist on list or not ...

I tried to use for this indexOf function - but it was the same ....

Maybe some of you will see the bug on this code or maybe my idea is not good ?

Thans for every tips and answers!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what your `items` array looks like, but it should work. `['test@example.com'].includes('test@example.com') === true`

Comment: Explicitly comparing to `true` and `false` is a fragile practice. Instead of `items.includes(email) === false` I'd write `!items.includes(email)`

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code. Have you tried `console.log(items);` and `console.log(email);` to see the actual values of those variables in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Hi, I used a console.log like that:

Comment: console.log(items);
console.log(items.includes(this.state.email));
console.log(email);

Comment: And even if the email is on array, the value is 'false'.

Comment: I tried change a boolean value (true and false) for a 'email - but this is not working too :(

Comment: Please comment here the results from logging "items" and "email".

Comment: @IwonaHajczewska Please do comment  items and email .

Comment: paste the result of `console.log(items)` and `console.log(email)`

Comment: [link to screen with result in console](http://www.serwisstron.pl/screen.png)

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to find an object property inside an array, not directly the value.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e) is what you what

Comment: `items.some(e => e.email === email)` is the equivalent for what you want.

Comment: Hi @RenanSouza! Thanks for your help - I was blind .....I hope that this will be working for a moment with your tips :)

Comment: i wanted to share this [gist](https://gist.github.com/alphapilgrim/007d7f65c0c0748891c7c8a1f0badddb) as a point of reference on how you can keep things more concise and dry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - it's working. I will analyze it carefully. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As we could see in the image pasted in comments ([why you should not doing that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)), you don't have an arrays of emails, you have an array of objects that includes an email in some of their properties (email).

You could use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) to return true or false if some element is present passing a function as parameter `items.some(o => o.email === mail)` [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) doesn't accept a functions as parameter.

```js
var items = [{
    "email": "some@email.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "some@email2.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "some@email3.com"
  }
]


var mail = "some@email.com";

var mail2 = "some@email4.com";

(items.some(o => o.email === mail)) ? console.log(true): console.log(false);

(items.some(o => o.email === mail2)) ? console.log(true): console.log(false);
```

Finally, please read why we shouldn't paste images of code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6121568

Comment: If you are leveraging information from the comments to create your answer, you could at least explain the case and/or edit the main question.

Comment: @RenanSouza of course, I've edited the answer

Comment: @RenanSouza I've just seen your comment proposing exactly the same solution.

Comment: No problem. It's okay. I just commented that here in your answer to ensure that anyone gets miss-lead because of this tricky situation for beginners. Sorry if I seemed rude.

Comment: No problem @RenanSouza.

Comment: Hi @Emeeus! Thanks for information about images - I will remeber about that in the future. And thanks for explanation of my problem.