# Jasmine: Test if array contains an object element with certain property without custom matcher

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an array:

```
const dummyArr = [
    { name: "a", city: "c1" },
    { name: "b", city: "c2" },
    { name: "z", city: "c3" }
]
```

I need to write a jasmine test, to verify if an element exists in an array with property `name: b`.
Not sure if I can use `arrayContaining` or `objectContaining` here.

Note: I need to verify this within `toHaveBeenCalledWith`

```
expect(obj.setArray).toHaveBeenCalledWith("personalDetails", .......)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Comment: `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` does not seem to apply; I'd use `expect(dummyArr.find(function(ele) {return ele.name === 'b';})).toBe(true);`.

Comment: `setArray` was spied upon `obj`.  
As I knew it was first time call to `setArray`, `dummyArr` was second  param and index of object element I wanted from `dummyArr`. This got me working  
`const elem = obj.setArray.calls.argsFor(0)[1];`  
`expect(elem[0].name).toEqual("b");`

Comment: the down-side with index access is that a specific order of items is being expected, which might or might not be given - and so the test might fail, even if the input is perfectly valid. access by property-name tends to be rather solid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one other way to do it without a custom matcher.
I am assuming `dummyArr` is your fake data, and you want to verify setArray gets called with the second element (named 'b').

```
expect(obj.setArray).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.arrayContaining([dummyArr.find(el => e.name === 'b')])
);
```

Depending on what you think it's readable, you could do the lookup before the expect:

```
const dummyEl = dummyArr.find(el => e.name === 'b');
expect(obj.setArray).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.arrayContaining([dummyEl]));
```

Note that this passes when setArray gets called with any array containing that element, e.g. the whole `dummyArr`. If you want an exact match, use `jasmine.arrayWithExactContents()` instead.