# how do I find 'abc' is in the array [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd',}]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

i want to know is there is a 'abc' in the [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}]

```
let a = 'abc'
let b = [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}]
```

```
if there is a in b{
   return 'yes'
} else {
   return 'no
}
```

//how can I do this and how to judge this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to find if an item is in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-if-an-item-is-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: @Veverke I would disagree. The duplicate post would search for the whole entry within an array. The OP here is asking to match a part of the entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Comment: @JamesLong: you are correct James, am removing my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is `some`:

```js
let a = 'abc'
let b = [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}];
let aInB = b.some(({ title }) => title == a);
console.log(aInB);
```

You could also use `includes` with `flatMap` and `Object.values`:

```js
let a = 'abc'
let b = [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}];
let aInB = b.flatMap(Object.values).includes(a) ? "Yes" : "No"; 
console.log(aInB);
```

Version without `flatMap` or `flat` (not well supported):

```js
let a = 'abc'
let b = [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}];
let aInB = b.map(Object.values).reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c)).includes(a) ? "Yes" : "No"; 
console.log(aInB);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var a = 'abc'
var b = [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}];
var aInB = b.map(function(e) {
  return Object.keys(e).map(function(key) {
    return e[key];
  });
}).reduce(function(a, c) {
  return a.concat(c);
}).indexOf(a) > -1 ? "Yes" : "No";
console.log(aInB);
```

Comment: You are making this more complex than it should be. The most canonically correct way to solve this is `Array#some`.

Comment: OK @str I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

Array​.prototype​.some()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```js
var a = 'abc';
var b = [
  {value: 'def'},
  {value: 'abc'},
  {value: 'ghi'}
];
const result = b.some(x => x.value === a);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

`Array#find` will return the matching item or `undefined` if it doesn't find a match, so you can use the result in your `if` statement.

```
let a = 'abc'
let b = [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}]
let c = b.find((d) => d.title === a);

if (c) {
    return 'yes';
} else {
    return 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var exist = b.find(function(element) {
  return element.title === a;
});
```

If you know property title is what you want to see, this should be your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (i=0; i<b.length; i++){
       if(i.title == a){
       console.log('yes')
       }
  }
```

Comment: Please consider correcting your code so that it will return "yes"/"no" instead of logging "yes" when the condition if satisfied

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 'ccc'
var b = [{title:'ccc'},{title:'abc'},{title:'ddd'}];

function presentAsTitle(a, b) {
    var flag = false;
    for (var i=0; i<=b.length; i++) {
        var item = b[i];
        if (item.title === a) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```