# Check if object as a specific value inside an array

Tags: javascript

I need to check if data is have a type as `acc-item`, if yes then I need assign a value `true` or `false` to this variable `hasAccordionLayout`.

```
data = [  
           {  
              type:"text",
              text:"This is just text"
           },
           {  
              type:"acc-item",
              text:"This is acc-item"
           },
           {  
              type:"acc-item",
              text:"This is acc-item 2"
           },
           {  
              type:"text",
              text:"This is just text"
           }
        ];
```

This is what I tried, But want to do it in a better way

```
this.hasAccordionLayout = (this.data.filter( function(content) {
            if(data.type === 'acc-item') {
              return data;
            }
          })).length > 0? true: false;
```

Comment: You should check the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) Array function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```
 this.hasAccordionLayout = data.some(e => e.type === 'acc-item');
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qn9L20g1/1/) for live demo.

Answer (score 0):

Updated, you can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function:

```
data.some(item => item.type === 'acc-item');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find):

```
this.hasAccordionLayout = this.data.find( d => d.type === 'acc-item') != undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function like this:

```js
data = [ { type:"text", text:"This is just text" }, { type:"acc-item", text:"This is acc-item" }, { type:"acc-item", text:"This is acc-item 2" }, { type:"text", text:"This is just text" } ];
        
const exist = key => data.some(ele=>ele.type === key);
        
console.log(exist('acc-item'));
```