# Check if element included in array of object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

so i'm trying to get value from checking if some elements included in array of object which i get from axios response.

the thing is the value is always false

here is the code:

```
 var ceck = this.state.cek;
    var coba = ceck.includes("16");
    console.log(coba);
```

and this is the output of var ceck:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id_esport: 16}
1: {id_esport: 15}
2: {id_esport: 22}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

thank you so much for your help

EDIT: i tried this

```
if (ceck.some(e => e.Name === '16')) {
  console.log("success")
}
```

nothing cames out

Comment: Second answer second code block: [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217584)

Comment: @NickParsons didn't works, already change e.name to e.id_esport also the 'vendors' to 'ceck'

Comment: can you please edit your question to show what you tried?

Comment: @NickParsons done

Comment: try: `ceck.some(e => e.id_esport === 16)` so remove the quotes around 16 and change e.Name to e.id_esport