# How return true if the array of object doesn't include object with this Id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to find if the array doesn't include tag with the selected tag id then return true. However this code is not working.

```
 !this.product.tags.includes(
        tag =>
          tag.type === 'shoes' &&
          tag.Id === this.selectedProduct[item][1].tag.Id,
      )
```

What is wrong and how can be it fixed?

Comment: Please stop adding the [ecmascript-5] tag to questions that are not about ECMAScript 5. This question uses `includes` and arrow functions, both of which were introduced in ECMAScript 2015, also known as ECMAScript 6. This question is also not about ECMAScript 6; it just happens to use constructs introduced in that version; it does not need the tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` is the wrong built-in function, you're looking for `some`

```
!this.product.tags.some(
        tag =>
          tag.type === 'shoes' &&
          tag.Id === this.selectedProduct[item][1].tag.Id,
      )
```

`includes` [checks if the provided argument exists in the given array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

`some` [checks if any of the elements of the array evaluate to true with the provided function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/some)

Answer (score 0):

```
 !this.product.tags.includes.some(
        tag =>
          typeof( tag.type )=== (typeOfvar) &&
          tag.Id === this.selectedProduct[item][1].tag.Id,
      )
```

works for me too! i have changed the tag.type with the typeof. This can helps you to make to code more dinamic.