# TypeScript - Unable to retrieve value from array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an interface `Country` as below in my `component.ts` class :

```
export interface Country{
  id: String;
  name: String;
  checked: false; 
}

const country: Country[] = [

   { id: 'India', name: 'India', checked: false},
   { id: 'USA', name: 'USA', checked: false},
   { id: 'Canada', name: 'Canada', checked: false},

]

selectedCountry: Country[] ;
```

On UI I have checkboxes for respective countries.

Let's say if user selects India/USA/Canada ( one at a time). So to handle the same, I am trying to write an `if-else` statement as :

```
if(this.selectedCountry.includes('India')
 // do something;
else if(this.selectedCountry.includes('USA')
 // do something;
else ...
```

But I am getting an error : **Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Country'.**

Can someone help me out figure the issue. Any help/pointers are highly appreciable.

Comment: `this.selectedCountry` contains `Country` objects, not strings. You need to check if a field of the objects matches that (not sure i you want `id` or `name`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Comment: What about if your contry array contains 100 countries, Are you going to code if-else for 100 times? I think this will not good solution.

Comment: @er-sho : Yeah, I am trying to figure what to do if the number of countries grow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
this.selectedCountry.some(c => c.name === "India");
```

> The some() method checks if any of the elements in an array pass a
> test (provided as a function).

For reusable code :

```
checkCountry(name: string): boolean{
  return this.selectedCountry.some(c => c.name === name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `this.selectedCountry` Object country?. How about `this.selectedCountry.id.includes('India')` ?