# How to match key value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have array of objects. I want to find the value in key which matches the word and if it's there it should return me true in console otherwise false.

I have array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "groupName": "harry",
    },
    {
        "groupName": "mike",
    }
]
```

And I want to match this key `groupName` with value like `Amy`. As we can see `Amy` in not there in `groupName` so it should return me false in console otherwise true if any of the `groupName` value is `Amy`.

How to achieve this using Javascript?

Comment: If you want it in the console, what do you want react to do?

Comment: If it returning true then I have to use `useState` to fire up a action. Otherwise if it is false then I would show alert in that. I just need the concept of matching it with the given word. That's it. Otherwise it would be lengthy question and answer to be asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217584/15497888)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `Array.some()`:

```js
const data = [{
    "groupName": "harry",
  },
  {
    "groupName": "mike",
  }
];

const result = data.some(obj => obj.groupName === 'harry');
console.log(result);
```

Or `Array.find()` to get the matching object:

```js
const data = [{
    "groupName": "harry",
  },
  {
    "groupName": "mike",
  }
];

const result = data.find(obj => obj.groupName === 'harry');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code (functional code style):

```js
const input = [
    {
        "groupName": "harry",
    },
    {
        "groupName": "mike",
    }
];

const findByPropertyName = name => arr => searched => arr.some(({ [name]: value}) => value === searched);

const findByGroupName = findByPropertyName('groupName');

const notFound = findByGroupName(input)('Amy');
const found = findByGroupName(input)('harry');

console.log(notFound);
console.log(found);
```

Comment: This answer wild yo! :)

Comment: I'd rather do `arr.some((x) => x[name] === searched);` instead of `arr.some(({ [name]: value}) => value === searched);` it just adds some unnecessary complexity

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just like the idea of giving a name to what I compare

Answer (score 1):

React has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve.

With just Javascript, you can do this using the [some Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this.

```js
const obj = [
    {
        "groupName": "harry",
    },
    {
        "groupName": "mike",
    }
]

const hasAmy = obj.some(x => x.groupName === 'Amy');
const hasMike = obj.some(x => x.groupName === 'mike');

console.log(hasAmy);
console.log(hasMike);
```