# Array check Empty or Null by all properties in object

Tags: javascript

```
const data = [

{
 name: "Kris",
 Tel: 000000,
 address:""
},
{
 name: "Mark",
 Tel: 111111,
 address:"USA"
},
{
 name: "Charie",
 Tel: null,
 address:""
},

]
```

I want to find() empty prop in this array if i has find empty or null
i want to return true and break to return so i dont' know how

expect: boolean type for return

from now i use

```
  const checkEmtry = () => data.forEach(e => Object.values(e).find(x => (x === null) || x === ''  ) )
```

Comment: What do you expect the function to return?

Comment: Please clarify the question... What is the desired output ? Object index in array ? Do you want to find all or just the first object ?

Comment: expect: boolean type for return

Comment: What do you want `true` and `false` to mean?

Comment: `forEach` will always return `undefined`. Consider using `every` or `some`, whichever is more appropriate?

Comment: to go a bit further from evolutionxbox's comment, it may be that you want to use `map` if you want every result. Anyway, this question should be clarified _a lot_ IMHO. For instance, you could give output expected data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`some` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (instead of `forEach` and `find`), which calls a callback for each element in the array and stops the first time the callback returns `true`.

```js
const checkEmtry = () => data.some(e => Object.values(e).some(x => x === null || x === ""));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: "Kris",
        Tel: 000000,
        address:""
    },
    {
        name: "Mark",
        Tel: 111111,
        address:"USA"
    },
    {
        name: "Charie",
        Tel: null,
        address:""
    },
];

const checkEmtry = () => data.some(e => Object.values(e).some(x => x === null || x === ""));

console.log(checkEmtry()); // true
```

To make the function more generally useful, you might accept the array to check as a parameter:

```
const checkEmtry = (data) => data.some(e => Object.values(e).some(x => x === null || x === ""));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^
```

---

Side note: I wasn't sure whether you meant `checkEntry` or `checkEmpty` so I left it `checkEmtry` above, but you probably want to change the `m` or the `t`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [

{
 name: "Kris",
 Tel: 000000,
 address:""
},
{
 name: "Mark",
 Tel: 111111,
 address:"USA"
},
{
 name: "Charie",
 Tel: null,
 address:""
},

]

function deepChecker(data) {
    let checkFilter = data.filter((d) => {
        return Object.values(d).filter((f) => { return f != "" && f != null }).length == Object.values(d).length
    })

    return data.length == checkFilter.length
}
console.log(deepChecker(data))
```