# Find Key value from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array structured like this:

```
var myArray = [{ value1: "a", value2: "b" }, { value1: "c", value2: "d" }, { value1: "e", value2: "a" }];
```

From this array, I want to check if there is a 'value1' that has the value 'a' and have the function return true or false.

Is this possible, or will I have to loop through All the Objects, checking each value and then returning true/false?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Comment: `myArray.some(e => e.value1 === 'a')`

Comment: Yes, Thanks! I did search around for a bit but I guess I didnt word it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array's [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method for this.

```js
var myArray = [{ value1: "a", value2: "b" }, { value1: "c", value2: "d" }, { value1: "e", value2: "a" }];

let out = myArray.some((ele)=>ele.value1 === "a")

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `some` array method like this:

`myArray.some(el => el.value1 === 'a')`

This will return `true` if there is such a value and `false` if not

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to do that.

```js
var myArray = [{ value1: "a", value2: "b" }, { value1: "c", value2: "d" }, { value1: "e", value2: "a" }];
console.log(!!myArray.find(element => element.value1 === "a"))
```