# How to return boolean value from filter method

Tags: javascript, filter

Searching an array for a value and returning true or false based on its presence.

Below is a working example of a filter method accessing the name property I care about:

```
  const renderNotDifferent = actions.filter(
    (action) => action.name !== "not-different"
  );
```

I want to create another property (boolean) if the `action.name` is === "should-be-different" - the two don't need to be combined, just including to show syntax.

Can anyone advise on the best approach?

Comment: did you try => action.new_attr = action.name !== "not-different"

Comment: Explain more about the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: Make it concrete. Provide concrete `actions` array, and expected output for it.

Comment: That's not what [filter does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I'd imagine you actually want [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Including filter to show the structure of the array - "action.name" - asking the question on how to access the value and set it to true or false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if Javascript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with `filter` - you can use `map` additionally:

```js
const renderNotDifferent = actions.filter(
  action => action.name !== 'not-different' 
).map(
  action => ({ ...action, shouldBeDifferent: action.name === 'should-be-different' })
);
```

Alternatively, if you want to actually mutate the existing objects, you could use a regular `for of` loop:

```js
for (const action of actions) {
  action.shouldBeDifferent = action.name === 'should-be-different'
}
```

---

UPDATE: Your question is a bit confusing. First it sounded like you want to add a property to each array element, but now with your edit I'm not sure anymore. In case you just want to have two booleans indicating whether any element has name `not-different` or `should-be-different`, respectively, then all you need it this:

```js
const hasNotDifferent = actions.some(action => action.name === 'not-different')
const hasShouldBeDifferent = actions.some(action => action.name === 'should-be-different')
```

Another option, especially useful (and fast) in case there are more names you need to check for, would be to use a `Set` with all the different names:

```js
const names = new Set(actions.map(action => action.name))

if (names.has('not-different')) {
  // render stuff
}

if (names.has('should-be-different')) {
  // render other stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help! is it possible to then access shouldBeDifferent outside of the map?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking - it's adding such a property to each action, as you asked. So you can access it on every individual action afterwards. But now it sounds like you meant something else - please check the update in my answer