# Exclude the list of objects listed on the variable from the filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I am working with JSON data and I filter some of the data out using .filter, I want it to exclude some categories and some products, which I can easily do by individually specifying on my filter return, but I reckon the list goes long and it doesn't look feasible the way it is.

I think I don't have to add the example JSON here, just imagine it has "category" and "product" for each data. Have a look how I process the data:

```
var myfilter = myjson.filter(function(c) {
    return (c.category != 3 && c.category!= 5 && c.category!= 8 && c.category!= 11 && c.product != 191 && c.product != 139 && c.product != "string instead of int");
  });
```

**^This above already does what I need. What I desire is to turn it into something like this:**

```
var excludedcats = [3, 5, 8, 11]
var excludedproducts = [191, 139, "string instead of int"]

var myfilter = myjson.filter(function(c) {
    return (c.category != excludedcats && c.product != excludedproducts);
  });
```

I am not a javascript pro, but I feel like this works like 'if' conditions and it has to keep repeating **c.category !=** and **c.product !=** for each, so I thought about some sort of loop until it specifies all of them. But I might be totally lost, too.

I  already did some research, but could be that since I don't even know all the technical terms either I failed to find what I'm looking for. Most relevant thing I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e), it didn't help me, just adding here to prove I researched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can leverage the `includes` method:

```
var myfilter = myjson.filter(function(c) {
  return !excludedcats.includes(c.category) && !excludedproducts.includes(c.product);
  //return (c.category != excludedcats && c.product != excludedproducts);
});
```

More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little more generic version.

```js
var myjson = [{
    category: 4,
    product: "string instead of int"
  },
  {
    category: 3,
    product: 0
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    product: "should keep"
  }
];

var exclusions = {
  category: [3, 5, 8, 11],
  product: [191, 139, "string instead of int"]
}


var myfilter = myjson.filter(function(c) {
  for (var key in exclusions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < exclusions[key].length; i++) {
      if (c[key] == exclusions[key][i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;

});

console.log(myfilter)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I think I would need this much thorough filtering in future if I, let's say want to exclude many different things than just categories and products. So for now I'll use Mario's suggestion. A question: Can I also add a static filter on top of those such as 'c.active = 1 && c.otherthing = 1' so it already excludes data active = 0 and otherthing = 0, and excludes these exclusions on top of that from the active ones?

Comment: This deserves its own question (or [edit] existing).

Comment: If I edit the question, the question would be about your answer. Anyways, I figured I can just replace "return true;" in your code with "return (c.active == 1 && c.otherthing == 1);" and it does exactly what I need.