# Efficient find and filter inside nested objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, performance, sorting, filter

Using Vue3 I have the following object $products

```
[{ 
   "id": 1, 
   "item": "Product 1", 
   "productcategories": [{ 
      "id": 300, 
      "title": "Category300" 
   },
   { 
      "id": 301, 
      "title": "Category301" 
   }], 
},
{ 
   "id": 2, 
   "item": "Product 2", 
   "productcategories": [{ 
      "id": 200, 
      "title": "Category200" 
   }], 
},
{ 
   "id": 3, 
   "item": "Product 3", 
   "productcategories": [{ 
      "id": 301, 
      "title": "Category301" 
   },
   { 
      "id": 309, 
      "title": "Category309" 
   }], 
}]
```

Note that:

```
//object type
console.log(typeof products.value);

//returns '300'
console.log(products.value[0]["productcategories"][0]["id"]);
```

Notice that each product can have multiple productcategories.

I want to filter this object and get an object containing those products where at least one of the productcategories id is 301. The ideal result $filtered_products would be:

```
[{ 
   "id": 1, 
   "department_id": 2, 
   "item": "Product 1", 
   "productcategories": [{ 
      "id": 300, 
      "title": "Category300" 
   },
   { 
      "id": **301**, 
      "title": "Category301" 
   }], 
},
{ 
   "id": 3, 
   "department_id": 2, 
   "item": "Product 1", 
   "productcategories": [{ 
      "id": **301**, 
      "title": "Category301" 
   },
   { 
      "id": 309, 
      "title": "Category309" 
   }], 
}]
```

I am open to any recomendations, my goal is to make this search as efficient as possible.

Comment: Define "as efficient as possible". If it's just a one-time search, then brute-forcing it is likely to be the most efficient way. If you want to be able to search this data repeatedly, "efficient" takes on a different meaning and you'll want to make some sort of map structure.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a JavaScript array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-a-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to do a one time search of the data, then the approach in @moonwave99's answer is probably as efficient as you'll ever need.

If, however, you need to repeatedly query this data with different category IDs, you should take the up-front hit of creating a lookup object in the form of a map, and use that instead:

```js
const productsByCategoryId =
  products
  .flatMap(p => p.productcategories.map(pc => [pc.id, p]))
  .reduce((map, [catId, product]) => {
    const arr = map.get(catId) ?? [];
    const newArr = [...arr, product];
    const deduped = [...new Set(newArr)];
    map.set(catId, deduped);
    return map;
  }, new Map);

console.log(productsByCategoryId.get(301));
```

```js
const products = [{
    "id": 1,
    "item": "Product 1",
    "productcategories": [{
        "id": 300,
        "title": "Category300"
      },
      {
        "id": 301,
        "title": "Category301"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "item": "Product 2",
    "productcategories": [{
      "id": 200,
      "title": "Category200"
    }],
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "item": "Product 3",
    "productcategories": [{
        "id": 301,
        "title": "Category301"
      },
      {
        "id": 309,
        "title": "Category309"
      }
    ],
  }
];

const productsByCategoryId =
  products
  .flatMap(p => p.productcategories.map(pc => [pc.id, p]))
  .reduce((map, [catId, product]) => {
    const arr = map.get(catId) ?? [];
    const newArr = [...arr, product];
    const deduped = [...new Set(newArr)];
    map.set(catId, deduped);
    return map;
  }, new Map);

console.log(productsByCategoryId.get(301));
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
function hasProductsWithCategory(category) {
  return data.filter(
    ({ productcategories }) => 
      productcategories.some(({ id }) => id === category
    )
  );
}
```

See results:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "item": "Product 1",
    "productcategories": [{
        "id": 300,
        "title": "Category300"
      },
      {
        "id": 301,
        "title": "Category301"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "item": "Product 2",
    "productcategories": [{
      "id": 200,
      "title": "Category200"
    }],
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "item": "Product 3",
    "productcategories": [{
        "id": 301,
        "title": "Category301"
      },
      {
        "id": 309,
        "title": "Category309"
      }
    ],
  }
]

function hasProductsWithCategory(category) {
  return data.filter(({
    productcategories
  }) => productcategories.some(({
    id
  }) => id === category))
}

const filtered = hasProductsWithCategory(301);

console.log(filtered);
```